# if xml file exists perform certain task

Tags: c#, xml

Hi my aim is to allow the xml file to write a new xml document if it does not exist and if it does exist then add elements to the xml file. The issue is that if gives me an error saying "xwriter does not exist in the current context" after the else if() statement. Thanx

so far i have tried this but its not working.

```
     private void button1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!File.Exists("doc.xml"))
        {
            XmlTextWriter xwriter = new XmlTextWriter("doc.xml", Encoding.UTF8);
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        }

        else if (File.Exists("doc.xml"))
        {
            xwriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            xwriter.WriteStartDocument();
            xwriter.WriteStartElement("myCourse");
            xwriter.WriteString("Test");
            xwriter.WriteEndElement();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Whatever your solution, any of these writers should be wrapped in `using` to avoid a leak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two primary problems

1) Your `else` statement tries to use a variable that is declared and created in the `if` statement. That is, xwriter simply does not exist in the `else`, because it is localised to the scope of the `if` branch of the code. To use it in the `else` statement as well, it must be declared before the `if` statement, so that it is available to both the `if` and `else` branches of the code.

2) You can't append to an XML file. If you create the xwriter outside the `if` statement, the code will compile and run, but your `else` block of code will simply overwrite the existing contents of the xml file.

To append to xml as you desire you need to open the file, seek to the location where the end tag of the root/document element starts, and then write using an xml writer so that it overwrites the end tag and forms new, valid xml. To close the file you must then append raw text that adds a new end tag for the root/document element so that the xml file remains valid.

Another (less efficient) approach is to load the XML from the file, and then rewrite the existing contents as well as the new data.

(You also don't need to check the existence of the file twice)

Answer (score 0):

The variable xwriter is only defined inside the first if block - you'll have to make it a global variable for it to be defined in the second block too.

Note that the XmlTextWriter constructor you use *truncates* the xml file if it exist, so you'll have to switch to the constructor taking a Stream parameter.

Also note that you shouldn't WriteStartDocument to an existing file...

All in all, Xml is not very good when you need to incrementally append data to existing files - consider switching to a different one if at all possible.